# Perform an action in every sub-directory using Bash

Tags: bash, command, directory-traversal

I am working on a script that needs to perform an action in every sub-directory of a specific folder.

What is the most efficient way to write that?

Comment: Please consider coming back through and reevaluating answers for correctness -- you've got an accepted answer getting a lot of views despite major bugs (f/e, running it over a directory where someone previously ran `mkdir 'foo * bar'` will cause `foo` and `bar` to be iterated over even if they don't exist, and the `*` will be replaced with a list of *all* filenames, even non-directory ones).

Comment: ...even worse is if someone ran `mkdir -p '/tmp/ /etc/passwd /'` -- if someone runs a script following this practice on `/tmp` to, say, find directories to delete, they could end up deleting `/etc/passwd`.

Answer (score 189, accepted):

```
for D in $(find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d); do
    //Do whatever you need with D
done
```

Comment: this will  break on white spaces

Comment: Also, note you need to tweak the `find` params if you want recursive or non-recursive behavior.

Comment: The above answer gave me the self directory as well, so the following worked a bit better for me:

`find . -mindepth 1 -type d`

Comment: @JoshC, both variants will break the directory created by `mkdir 'directory name with spaces'` into four separate words.

Comment: I needed to add `-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1` or it went too deep.

Comment: The same in a single line (can be run at command-line): `for D in \`find . -type d\`; do
    //Do whatever you need with D; done`

Comment: @ScrappyDev just replace both with `-depth 1`

Comment: @DataDino `-depth Process  each  directory's contents before the directory itself.` I think it isn't a replace for `mindepth` and `maxdepth`.

Comment: @TNT You are correct that it would traverse in a different order. I might have misunderstood the desired outcome, thanks for bringing this up :)

Comment: If using `find` I think one might as well get rid of the for loop and use `find` with its `exec` argument instead.

Answer (score 338):

A version that avoids creating a sub-process:

```
for D in *; do
    if [ -d "${D}" ]; then
        echo "${D}"   # your processing here
    fi
done
```

Or, if your action is a single command, this is more concise:

```
for D in *; do [ -d "${D}" ] && my_command; done
```

Or an even more concise version ([thanks @enzotib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000613/bash-for-each-directory/4000741#comment4287856_4000741)). Note that in this version each value of `D` will have a trailing slash:

```
for D in */; do my_command; done
```

Comment: You can avoid the `if` or `[` with: `for D in */; do`

Comment: +1 because directory names don't begin with ./ as opposed to accepted answer

Comment: This one is correct even up to spaces in the directory names +1

Comment: There is one problem with the last command: if you are in a directory without subdirectories; it will return "*/". So better use the second command `for D in *; do [ -d "${D}" ] && my_command; done` or a combination of the two latest: `for D in */; do [ -d $D ] && my_command; done`

Comment: Note that this answer ignores hidden directories. To include hidden directories use `for D in .* *; do` instead `for D in *; do`.

Comment: note for noobs like me that if you're wanting to do this on a directory that isn't the current, the syntax is `for D in ./directory/*; do`

Comment: use `${D%/*}` instead of $D to trim the trailing slash.

Comment: @Hafthor `${D%/}` is probably safer so extra characters after the `/` aren't accidentally removed.

Answer (score 133):

The simplest **non recursive** way is:

```
for d in */; do
    echo "$d"
done
```

The `/` at the end tells, use directories only.

**There is no need for**

- find
- awk
- ...

Comment: Note: this will not include dot dirs (which can be a good thing, but it important to know).

Comment: Useful to note that you can use `shopt -s dotglob` to include dotfiles/dotdirs when expanding wildcards. See also: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html

Comment: I think you meant `/*` instead of `*/` with `/` representing the path you want to use.

Comment: @Shule `/*` would be for absolute path whereas `*/` would include the subdirectories from the current location

Comment: helpful hint: if you need to trim the trailing '/' from $d, use `${d%/*}`

Answer (score 24):

#### Use `find` command.

In GNU `find`, you can use `-execdir` parameter:

```
find . -type d -execdir realpath "{}" ';'
```

or by using `-exec` parameter:

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c 'cd -P "$0" && pwd -P' {} \;
```

or with `xargs` command:

```
find . -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -L1 sh -c 'cd "$0" && pwd && echo Do stuff'
```

---

Or using *for* loop:

```
for d in */; { echo "$d"; }
```

<sup>For recursivity try extended globbing (`**/`) instead (enable by: `shopt -s extglob`).</sup>

---

For more examples, see: [How to go to each directory and execute a command?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7470165/55075) at SO

Comment: `-exec {} +` is POSIX-specified, `-exec sh -c 'owd=$PWD; for arg; do cd -- "$arg" && pwd -P; cd -- "$owd"; done' _ {} +` is another legal option, and invokes fewer shells than `-exec sh -c '...' {} \;`.

Answer (score 15):

Handy one-liners

```
for D in *; do echo "$D"; done
for D in *; do find "$D" -type d; done ### Option A

find * -type d ### Option B
```

Option A is correct for folders with spaces in between. Also, generally faster since it doesn't print each word in a folder name as a separate entity.

```
# Option A
$ time for D in ./big_dir/*; do find "$D" -type d > /dev/null; done
real    0m0.327s
user    0m0.084s
sys     0m0.236s

# Option B
$ time for D in `find ./big_dir/* -type d`; do echo "$D" > /dev/null; done
real    0m0.787s
user    0m0.484s
sys     0m0.308s
```

Answer (score 10):

`find . -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 my_command`

Comment: can I feed the return value of that find into a for loop? This is part of a larger script...

Comment: @Mike, unlikely.  $? will probably get you the status of the find or the xargs command, rather than `my_command`.

Answer (score 7):

This will create a subshell (which means that variable values will be lost when the `while` loop exits):

```
find . -type d | while read -r dir
do
    something
done
```

This won't:

```
while read -r dir
do
    something
done < <(find . -type d)
```

Either one will work if there are spaces in directory names.

Comment: For even better handling of weird filenames (including names that end with whitespace and/or include linefeeds), use `find ... -print0` and `while IFS="" read -r -d $'\000' dir`

Comment: @GordonDavisson, ...indeed, I'd even argue that `-d ''` is less misleading about bash syntax and capabilities, since `-d $'\000'` implies (falsely) that `$'\000'` is in some way different from `''` -- indeed, one could readily (and again, falsely) infer from it that bash supports Pascal-style strings (length-specified, able to contain NUL literals) rather than C strings (NUL delimited, unable to contain NULs).

Answer (score 6):

the accepted answer will break on white spaces if the directory names have them, and the preferred syntax is `$()` for bash/ksh. Use `GNU find` `-exec`  option with `+;` eg

`find .... -exec mycommand +;`  `#this is same as passing to xargs`

or use a while loop

```
find .... | while read -r D
do
    # use variable `D` or whatever variable name you defined instead here
done
```

Comment: what param will hold the directory name?

eg, chmod +x $DIR_NAME

(yes, i know there is a chmod option for only directories)

Comment: There is one subtle difference between `find -exec` and passing to `xargs`: `find` will ignore the exit value of the command being executed, while `xargs` will fail on a nonzero exit. Either might be correct, depending on your needs.

Comment: `find ... -print0 | while IFS= read -r d` is safer -- supports names that begin or end in whitespace, and names that contain newline literals.

Answer (score 6):

You could try:

```
#!/bin/bash
### $1 == the first args to this script
### usage: script.sh /path/to/dir/

for f in `find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d`; do
  cd "$f"
  <your job here>
done
```

or similar...

Explanation:

`find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d` :
Only find directories with a maximum recursive depth of 1 (only the subdirectories of $1) and minimum depth of 1 (excludes current folder `.`)

Comment: This is buggy -- try with a directory name with spaces. See [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29), and [DontReadLinesWithFor](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Comment: Directory name with spaces is enclosed in quotes and therefore works and OP is not trying to read lines from file.

Comment: it works in the `cd "$f"`. It doesn't work when the output from `find` is string-split, so you'll have the separate pieces of the name as separate values in `$f`, making how well you do or don't quote `$f`'s expansion moot.

Comment: I didn't say they *were* trying to read lines from a file. `find`'s output is line-oriented (one name to a line, in theory -- but see below) with the default `-print` action.

Comment: Line-oriented output, as from `find -print` is not a *safe* way to pass arbitrary filenames, since one can run something `mkdir -p $'foo\n/etc/passwd\nbar'` and get a directory that has `/etc/passwd` as a separate line in its name. Handling names from files in `/upload` or `/tmp` directories without care is a great way to get privilege escalation attacks.

Comment: In general, not speaking specifically to UNIX or to filenames, to unambiguously distinguish where one string ends and the next one begins in a list, one must either pass length out-of-band or use a sigil as separator that can't be present in one of those strings. The only character that can't be present in a filename on UNIX systems is NUL, so the only way to safely pass a list of filenames is a NUL-delimited list. (Since arguments on UNIX are C strings, and thus NUL-delimited, this is why `find ... -exec` is safe: Arguments passed on an argv list are individually terminated by NULs).

Comment: ...anyhow, you can easily test this yourself. `( tempdir=$(mktemp -d "$PWD"/tempdir.XXXXXX) && cd "$tempdir" && { mkdir 'directory with spaces' $'directory\nwith\nnewlines'; for d in $(find . -type d -print); do echo "Found: $d"; done; }; rm -rf "$tempdir" )` and you'll see each word on its own separate line in the output, with its own `Found:` prefix.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to perform an action INSIDE the folder and not ON folder.

Explanation: You have many pdfs and you would like to concetrate them inside a single folder.
my folders

```
   AV 001/
   AV 002/
```

- `for D in *; do cd "$D";`                                   # VERY
  DANGEROUS COMMAND - DONT USE
  #-- missing "", it will list files too. It can go up too.
- `for d in */; do  cd "$d"; echo $d; cd ..; done;`           # works
  succesfully
- `for D in "$(ls -d */)"; do cd "$D"; done;`           #
  bash: cd: $'Athens Voice 001/\nAthens Voice 002/' - there is no such
  folder
- `for D in "$(*/)"; do cd "$D"; done;`                 # bash: Athens
  Voice 001/: is folder
- `` for D in "$(`find . -type d`)"; do cd $D; done; ``          # bash: ./Athens: there is no such folder or file
- `for D in *; do  if [ -d "${D}" ] then cd ${D};  done;`     # many
  arguments

Comment: missing "", it will list files too. It can go up too.