# How to go to each directory and execute a command?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, find

How do I write a bash script that goes through each directory inside a parent_directory and **executes** a **command** in **each directory**.

The directory structure is as follows:

> parent_directory (name could be anything - doesnt follow a pattern)
>
> - 001 (directory names follow this pattern)
>
>   - 0001.txt (filenames follow this pattern)
>   - 0002.txt
>   - 0003.txt
> - 002
>
>   - 0001.txt
>   - 0002.txt
>   - 0003.txt
>   - 0004.txt
> - 003
>
>   - 0001.txt
>
> the number of directories is unknown.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

You can do the following, when your current directory is `parent_directory`:

```
for d in [0-9][0-9][0-9]
do
    ( cd "$d" && your-command-here )
done
```

The `(` and `)` create a subshell, so the current directory isn't changed in the main script.

Comment: It doesn't matter here because the wildcard doesn't match anything else than numbers, but in the general case, you basically always want to put the directory name in double quotes inside the loop.  `cd "$d"` would be better in that it transfers to situations where the wildcard does match files whose names contain whitespace and/or shell metacharacters.

Comment: (All of the answers here seem to have the same flaw, but it matters the most in the top-voted answer.)

Comment: Also, the vast majority of commands don't actually care in which directory you execute them.  `for f in foo bar; do cat "$f"/*.txt; done >output` is functionally equivalent to `cat foo/*.txt bar/*.txt >output`.  However, `ls` is one command that does produce slightly different output depending on how you pass it arguments; similarly, a `grep` or `wc` which outputs a relative file name will be different if you run it from a subdirectory (but often, you want to avoid going into a subdirectory precisely for that reason).

Comment: Thanks for the answer I used it like so `for d in ./packages/*-spa/; do (cd "$d" && cp test.env .env); done`

Comment: A very similar problem, If I have a bash script in parent directory, can I run it using this formalism? I have a bash script that needs to run in each subdirectory.

Answer (score 259):

This [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/77491/26946) posted by [Todd](https://askubuntu.com/users/27704/todd-partridge-gen2ly) helped me.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d \( ! -name . \) -exec bash -c "cd '{}' && pwd" \;
```

The `\( ! -name . \)`  avoids executing the command in current directory.

Comment: And if you only want to run the command in certain folders: `find FOLDER* -maxdepth 0 -type d \( ! -name . \) -exec bash -c "cd '{}' && pwd" \;`

Comment: I had to do `-exec bash -c 'cd "$0" && pwd' {} \;` since some directories contained single quotes and some double quotes.

Comment: You also could omit current directory by adding `-mindepth 1`

Comment: How to change this to a function accept a command like "git remote get-url origin` instead of `pwd` directly?

Comment: `disd(){find . -maxdepth 1 -type d \( ! -name . \) -exec bash -c 'cd "{}" && "$@"' \;}` not work.

Comment: For me the command didn't work as it is. Taking cue from the comments by CharlieGorichanaz and roachsinai, a subtle change worked - replace " by ' and vice-versa

Comment: If you're in a git repo and you don't want to break everything remember to skip hidden folders like `find .  -not -path '*/.*' -type f -exec sed -i 's/\r//' {} \;`

Answer (score 75):

You can achieve this by piping and then using `xargs`. The catch is you need to use the `-I` flag which will replace the substring in your bash command with the substring passed by each of the `xargs`.

```
ls -d */ | xargs -I {} bash -c "cd '{}' && pwd"
```

You may want to replace `pwd` with whatever command you want to execute in each directory.

Comment: I don't know why this has not been upvoted, but the simplest script I found so far.
Thanks

Comment: This one is the best one as any command you run with xargs with generate an exit code and follow up actions can be taken from the value of '$?'. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 64):

If you're using GNU `find`, you can try `-execdir` parameter, e.g.:

```
find . -type d -execdir realpath "{}" ';'
```

or (as per [@gniourf_gniourf comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470165/how-to-go-to-each-directory-and-execute-a-command/26495371?noredirect=1#comment53694906_26495371)):

```
find . -type d -execdir sh -c 'printf "%s/%s\n" "$PWD" "$0"' {} \;
```

<sup>Note: You can use `${0#./}` instead of `$0` to fix `./` in the front.</sup>

or more practical example:

```
find . -name .git -type d -execdir git pull -v ';'
```

---

If you want to include the current directory, it's even simpler by using `-exec`:

```
find . -type d -exec sh -c 'cd -P -- "{}" && pwd -P' \;
```

or using `xargs`:

```
find . -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -L1 sh -c 'cd "$0" && pwd && echo Do stuff'
```

Or similar example suggested by [@gniourf_gniourf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470165/how-to-go-to-each-directory-and-execute-a-command/26495371?noredirect=1#comment53694088_26495371):

```
find . -type d -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
# ...
done
```

<sup>The above examples support directories with spaces in their name.</sup>

---

Or by assigning into bash array:

```
dirs=($(find . -type d))
for dir in "${dirs[@]}"; do
  cd "$dir"
  echo $PWD
done
```

<sup>Change `.` to your specific folder name. If you don't need to run recursively, you can use: `dirs=(*)` instead. The above example doesn't support directories with spaces in the name.</sup>

So as [@gniourf_gniourf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470165/how-to-go-to-each-directory-and-execute-a-command/26495371#comment53694064_26495371) suggested, the only proper way to put the output of find in an array without using an explicit loop will be available in Bash 4.4 with:

```
mapfile -t -d '' dirs < <(find . -type d -print0)
```

---

Or not a recommended way (which involves [parsing of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)):

```
ls -d */ | awk '{print $NF}' | xargs -n1 sh -c 'cd $0 && pwd && echo Do stuff'
```

<sup>The above example would ignore the current dir (as requested by OP), but it'll break on names with the spaces.</sup>

See also:

- [Bash: for each directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4000613/55075) at SO
- [How to enter every directory in current path and execute script?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/77482/how-to-enter-every-directory-in-current-path-and-execute-script) at SE Ubuntu

Comment: The only proper way to put the output of `find` in an array without using an explicit loop will be available in Bash 4.4 with `mapfile -t -d '' dirs < <(find . -type d -print0)`. Until then, your only option is to use a loop (or defer the operation to `find`).

Comment: In fact, you don't really need the `dirs` array; you could loop on `find`'s output (safely) like so: `find . -type d -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do ...; done`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I'm visual and always trying to find/make the things which look simple. E.g. I've [this script](https://github.com/EA31337/EA31337-Sets/blob/master/_scripts/run_backtests.sh) and by using bash array is easy and readable for me (by separating the logic into smaller pieces, instead of using pipes). Introducing additional pipes, `IFS`, `read`, it gives the impression of additional complexity. I'll have to think about it, maybe there is some easier way of doing it.

Comment: If by _easier_ you mean _broken_ then yes, there are easier ways of doing. Now don't worry, all these `IFS` and `read` (as you say) become a second nature as you get used to them… they are part of the canonical and idiomatic ways of writing scripts.

Comment: By the way, your first command `find . -type d -execdir echo $(pwd)/{} ';'` doesn't do what you want (the `$(pwd)` is expanded before `find` is even executed)…

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf When I've tried to run `pwd` before it's expanded: `find . -type d -execdir pwd ';'`, it doesn't work as expected as well (it's just showing the same dir), despite `find` returns different dirs.

Answer (score 26):

If the toplevel folder is known you can just write something like this:

```
for dir in `ls $YOUR_TOP_LEVEL_FOLDER`;
do
    for subdir in `ls $YOUR_TOP_LEVEL_FOLDER/$dir`;
    do
      $(PLAY AS MUCH AS YOU WANT);
    done
done
```

On the $(PLAY AS MUCH AS YOU WANT); you can put as much code as you want.

Note that I didn't "cd" on any directory.

Cheers,

Comment: There are a couple of instances of ["Useless Use of `ls`"](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#ls) here - you could just do `for dir in $YOUR_TOP_LEVEL_FOLDER/*` instead.

Comment: Well, maybe it's useless in a general sense but it allows to do filtering directly in the ls (i.e all directories ended with .tmp). That's why I used the `ls $dir` expression

Comment: Will `for subdir in 'ls $YOUR_TOP_LEVEL_FOLDER/$dir';` traverse multiple directories nesting like `parent/child1/child1_1/child1_1_1/`? Or just one directory deep into the parent?

Answer (score 23):

```
for dir in PARENT/*
do
  test -d "$dir" || continue
  # Do something with $dir...
done
```

Comment: And this is very easy to comprehend!

Answer (score 7):

While one liners are good for quick and dirty usage, I prefer below more verbose version for writing scripts. This is the template I use which takes care of many edge cases and allows you to write more complex code to execute on a folder. You can write your bash code in the function dir_command. Below, dir_coomand implements tagging each repository in git as an example. Rest of the script calls dir_command for each folder in directory. The example of iterating through only given set of folder is also include.

```
#!/bin/bash

#Use set -x if you want to echo each command while getting executed
#set -x

#Save current directory so we can restore it later
cur=$PWD
#Save command line arguments so functions can access it
args=("$@")

#Put your code in this function
#To access command line arguments use syntax ${args[1]} etc
function dir_command {
    #This example command implements doing git status for folder
    cd $1
    echo "$(tput setaf 2)$1$(tput sgr 0)"
    git tag -a ${args[0]} -m "${args[1]}"
    git push --tags
    cd ..
}

#This loop will go to each immediate child and execute dir_command
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d \( ! -name . \) | while read dir; do
   dir_command "$dir/"
done

#This example loop only loops through give set of folders    
declare -a dirs=("dir1" "dir2" "dir3")
for dir in "${dirs[@]}"; do
    dir_command "$dir/"
done

#Restore the folder
cd "$cur"
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't get the point with the formating of the file, since you only want to iterate through folders... Are you looking for something like this?

```
cd parent
find . -type d | while read d; do
   ls $d/
done
```

Comment: you should add `-maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1` in find as well else it would pick up all subdirectories too !

Answer (score 3):

you can use

```
find .
```

to search all files/dirs in the current directory recurive

Than you can pipe the output the xargs command like so

```
find . | xargs 'command here'
```

Comment: This is not what was asked.

Answer (score 3):

You could run sequence of commands in each folder in 1 line like:

```
for d in PARENT_FOLDER/*; do (cd "$d" && tar -cvzf $d.tar.gz *.*)); done
```

Answer (score 2):

In the below code you are able to use a pattern instead of * to filter unwanted files.

Modify -mindepth and maxdepth 1 to a higher number in order to dive deeper. Value of 1 will go only 1 level deep. Remove these min and max depth arguments completely to go infinitely deep.

**Note:** Only use the below code when you know there are no spaces in the folder names. See [here](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2044) for details.

```
#!/bin/bash
for folder in $(find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d \( -name "*" \) );
do
  cd "$folder" || exit

  echo "Folder: $folder"

  cd -
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for p in [0-9][0-9][0-9];do
    (
        cd $p
        for f in [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*.txt;do
            ls $f; # Your operands
        done
    )
done
```

Comment: You'd need to change back up the directory again, or do the `cd` in a subshell.

Comment: Downvote: the edit lost the `cd` so this code doesn't actually do anything useful.